# Can I configure VSCode to auto copy my file to another file whenever I save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode. Is there a way VSCode can auto save all my saves to a sequence of files? For example, my file is named `foo.c`, after some editing, the first time I save the file, there is a file `foo.c_1` generated, the 2nd time `foo.c_2`, the 3rd `foo.c_3`, etc.

[savevers.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=89) is what I have been using for vim. It is super convenient, say, when I want to retrieve a version I did the day before.

[Update] Yes, thanks life888888, timeline works great, it saves the history after I close and reopen the project folder.

Comment: This is what version control is for. Use Git, commit your files regularly, prosper.

Comment: google `vs code save local history` , you can find many youtube videos tech this. `timeline` -> `local history`, vs code already built in this function.